# Custom Actionbar View - not filling height

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

My custom actionbar view is not filling height.. It appears as in the picture.

[image]

I am using AppCompatActivity (ActionBarActivity is deprecated).

```
 ActionBar actionBar = pActivity.getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(pActivity);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.action_new, null);

    TextView text_back = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.text_back);
    text_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pActivity.onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    TextView text_reset = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.text_reset);
    text_reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions( ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    Toolbar parent = (Toolbar) mCustomView.getParent();
    parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
```

Following is the action_new layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bottom_green">    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:text="BACK" android:id="@+id/text_back"  android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"   android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:textColor="@color/text_in_green" android:padding="10dp" android:textSize="18dp" android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        />    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="RESET" android:id="@+id/text_reset" android:textColor="@color/text_in_green" android:textSize="18dp" android:layout_centerVertical="true"  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:padding="10dp" android:paddingRight="15dp" android:paddingEnd="15dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have you checked `action_new` for any `margin/padding`?

Comment: Please attach the XML-layout of "action_new". Otherwise it is hard to answer your question.

Comment: Please show me the layout file so that we can figure it out clearly.

Comment: post your layout file, R.layout.action_new?

Comment: @JitenderDev check the xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix, add `android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"` to your RelativeLayout

For better handling and more freely customized, you should use toolbar

Comment: Thanks... its worked... 
I added a toolbar... I think it will also work without toolbar.
(Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);)

Answer (score 0):

You have added a padding of 10 dp.

Remove `android:padding="10dp"` from both TextViews. It should work fine.